# How to GET file and stream it into a POST request with Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to write a function that does a GET request to download a file from server A, then immediately POST the file to server B.

I'm trying to look for a way to do it by streaming the output of the GET request into the input of the POST request.

The [following article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/transferring-files-aws-lambda) discusses doing this in nodeJS. How would I do this with Python Requests?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Are you attempting to concurrently GET a request, then pipe that to a POST request? The reason I ask is because you've referenced node.js which should be able to pipe GET content into POST request simultaneously. Python can do that too but it's a bit tricky and it involves more than just `requests`

Comment: That's a possibility but I'm not set on it. I'm gonna try Martijn's answer and report back

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the *raw connection object* from a streaming GET request, as a file to a POST request:

```
r = requests.get(get_url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    r.raw.decode_content = True  # decompress as you read
    files = {
        'fieldname': ('filename', r.raw, r.headers['Content-Type'])
    }
    requests.post(post_url, files=files)
```

To use the `response.raw` file-like object will not, by default, decode compressed responses (with GZIP or deflate), but you can force it to decompress for you anyway by setting the `decode_content` attribute to `True` (requests sets it to `False` to control decoding itself).

I assumed that the file was to be POSTed as part of a `multipart/form-data` request. If you need to post the data directly, use `data=r.raw` instead.